# How get fundamental cycles with R + Igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the next graph,

```
library(igraph)
library(Cairo)

g<-graph(c(0,1,0,4,0,9,1,7,1,9,2,9,2,3,2,5,3,6,3,9,4,5,4,8,5,8,6,7,6,8,7,8),n=10,dir=FALSE)
V(g)$name<-c(1:10)
V(g)$label<-V(g)$name
coords <- c(0,0,13.0000,0,5.9982,5.9991,7.9973,7.0009,-1.0008,11.9999,0.9993,11.0002,7.9989,13.0009,10.9989,14.0009,5.9989,14.0009,7.0000,4.0000)
coords <- matrix(coords, 10,2,byrow=T)
plot(g,layout=coords)
```

I'd like to get cycles of 4 , 5...n vertex, for example in these graph i'd like to get cycles of 5,

```
1 10 3 6  5
2  8 7 4 10
3  4 7 9  6
```

I don't want cycles like

`1 2 8 9 5` which have vertex inside of this cycle.

Comment: have you studied the help page for `?graph`?

Comment: obviously, i've studied the manual and ?graph, why? have you seen something according to that? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think to begin with, let's modify your code a little to make it easier on someone to produce the graph "out of the box".

Cairo is not needed for this code, so let's remove it. Replace the graph creation line with these two lines:

```
your.nodes<-c(0,1,0,4,0,9,1,7,1,9,2,9,2,3,2,5,3,6,3,9,4,5,4,8,5,8,6,7,6,8,7,8)
g<-graph(your.nodes+1,dir=FALSE)
```

That `your.nodes+1` exists because graph()/igraph processes 0 id in special way. Perhaps topic for a different time.

At this point, you should be able to plot the graph from your last line. [Plot of igraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i34m.jpg)

Now looking at the plot, I'm wondering why `1 2 8 9 5` is not needed. I guess I'm not sure what you mean by a "vertex inside a cycle". As far as getting fundamental cycle goes, look at [`fundCycles()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggm/functions/fundCycles) from `ggm` package.

(PS: Also, sorry for posting this as an answer. I don't have enough reputation points to ask this in comments, and embed a picture.)